# How to create a OpenSocial Widget in LifeRay to connect to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, liferay, opensocial

I need some example or steps that I can follow to develop a LifeRay widget using OpenSocial and connect to SharePoint document library.

I just want to display data from SP doc library inside a portlet on the LifeRay portal.

Sorry, pretty new on LifeRay platform.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know Liferay or Opensocial, but I assume you can somehow inject javascript into it.

So a possibility is to use Sharepoint Rest Services, using JSONP (assuming the sharepoint server is in a different domain than the Liferay server) and consume the data from there. Here is a description on how to use them:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx